# Derived DataFrame column from other column without writing any loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns (verb and occurrence). I was able to create a new column which determines the character count for the verb (i.e., length):

```
df['length'] = df['verb'].str.len()
```

The second requirement is to create a new column with a text. If `ocurrence` is equal to 1, then write `'Unique'`; if `ocurrence` is less than or equal to 5, then write `'Medium'`; otherwise `'High'`...

...This is the code I've written so far...

```
df['class'] = 'Unique' if df['ocurrence'] == 1 else 'Medium' if df['ocurrence'] <= 5 else 'High'
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['class'] = pd.cut(df.occurrence, bins=[0,1,5,np.inf], labels=['Unique','Medium','High'])
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'occurrence':np.random.randint(0,10,10)})
>>> df
   occurrence
0           5
1           1
2           6
3           7
4           5
5           7
6           7
7           1
8           2
9           7

df['class'] = pd.cut(df.occurrence, bins=[0,1,5,np.inf], labels=['Unique','Medium','High'])
>>> df
   occurrence   class
0           5  Medium
1           1  Unique
2           6    High
3           7    High
4           5  Medium
5           7    High
6           7    High
7           1  Unique
8           2  Medium
9           7    High
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Ternary statements aren't vectorised. With Pandas you should use Pandas / NumPy methods for columnar operations. In this case, you can use `np.select`:

```
conditions = [df['occurrence'] == 1, df['occurrence'] <= 5]
choices = ['Unique', 'Medium']

df['class'] = np.select(conditions, choices, 'High')
```